# Azure bicep Storage Account loop blobs error

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-bicep

I have this script to loop over an array of storage account and create them with some default configurations.

```
param storageAccounts array = [
  'storage2312'
  'storage2we1'
]

resource storage_Accounts 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts@2021-04-01' = [ for storageName in storageAccounts :{
  name: storageName
  location: 'westeurope'
  sku: {
    name: 'Standard_RAGRS'
  }
  kind: 'StorageV2'
  properties: {
    allowCrossTenantReplication: true
    minimumTlsVersion: 'TLS1_2'
    allowBlobPublicAccess: false
    allowSharedKeyAccess: true
    networkAcls: {
      bypass: 'AzureServices'
      virtualNetworkRules: []
      ipRules: []
      defaultAction: 'Allow'
    }
    supportsHttpsTrafficOnly: true
    encryption: {
      services: {
        file: {
          keyType: 'Account'
          enabled: true
        }
        blob: {
          keyType: 'Account'
          enabled: true
        }
      }
      keySource: 'Microsoft.Storage'
    }
    accessTier: 'Hot'
  }
}]
resource storage_Accounts_name_default 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/blobServices@2021-04-01' = [ for (storageName, i) in storageAccounts :{
  parent: storage_Accounts[i]
  name: storageName
  properties: {
    changeFeed: {
      enabled: false
    }
    restorePolicy: {
      enabled: false
    }
    containerDeleteRetentionPolicy: {
      enabled: true
      days: 7
    }
    cors: {
      corsRules: []
    }
    deleteRetentionPolicy: {
      enabled: true
      days: 30
    }
    isVersioningEnabled: true
  }
}]
```

The scripts works just fine and the storage accounts get created but the script at the end throws the following error:

```
{"status":"Failed","error":{"code":"DeploymentFailed","message":"At least one resource deployment operation failed. Please list deployment operations for details. Please see https://aka.ms/DeployOperations for usage details.","details":[{"code":"NotFound","message":"{\r\n  \"error\": {\r\n    \"code\": \"HttpResourceNotFound\",\r\n    \"message\": \"The request url resourcegroups/storageAccounts/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/storage2we1/blobServices/storage2we1?api-version=2021-04-01 is not found.\"\r\n  }\r\n}"},{"code":"NotFound","message":"{\r\n  \"error\": {\r\n    \"code\": \"HttpResourceNotFound\",\r\n    \"message\": \"The request url /resourcegroups/storageAccounts/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/storage2312/blobServices/storage2312?api-version=2021-04-01 is not found.\"\r\n  }\r\n}"}]}}
```

When create a storage account manually, I have as a default container the `$logs` but when I run the script, and the storage account get created, under container I don't have anything, which I presume that the error is due to that.
With bicep do I have to declare the default container?
Any help and explanation would be most welcome.

thank you so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the sample provided [`here`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.storage/storageaccounts/blobservices?tabs=bicep), please change the following line of code (in your 2nd snippet where you're configuring blob service) from:

```
name: storageName
```

to

```
name: 'default'
```

So effectively, your bicep template would be something like:

```
param storageAccounts array = [
  'storage2'
]
resource storage_Accounts 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts@2021-04-01' = [ for storageName in storageAccounts :{
  name: storageName
  location: 'westeurope'
  sku: {
    name: 'Standard_RAGRS'
    tier: 'Standard'
  }
  kind: 'StorageV2'
  properties: {
    allowCrossTenantReplication: true
    minimumTlsVersion: 'TLS1_2'
    allowBlobPublicAccess: false
    allowSharedKeyAccess: true
    networkAcls: {
      bypass: 'AzureServices'
      virtualNetworkRules: []
      ipRules: []
      defaultAction: 'Allow'
    }
    supportsHttpsTrafficOnly: true
    encryption: {
      services: {
        file: {
          keyType: 'Account'
          enabled: true
        }
        blob: {
          keyType: 'Account'
          enabled: true
        }
      }
      keySource: 'Microsoft.Storage'
    }
    accessTier: 'Hot'
  }
}]

resource storage_Accounts_name_default 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/blobServices@2021-04-01' = [ for (storageName, i) in storageAccounts :{
  parent: storage_Accounts[i]
  name: 'default'
  properties: {
    changeFeed: {
      enabled: false
    }
    restorePolicy: {
      enabled: false
    }
    containerDeleteRetentionPolicy: {
      enabled: true
      days: 7
    }
    cors: {
      corsRules: []
    }
    deleteRetentionPolicy: {
      enabled: true
      days: 30
    }
    isVersioningEnabled: true
  }
}]
```

Comment: That worked, you were right. thank you very much Gaurav.

Answer (score 0):

Here is alternative solution with more generics

Definition of the containers to create

```
var containerNames = [
  'web'
  'blob'
  'test'
]
```

Next we need definiton of the storage account

```
resource storageAccount 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts@2022-09-01' = {
  name: replace(storageName, '-', '')
  location: location
  kind:'StorageV2'
  sku:{
    name: skuName
  }
  properties: {
    minimumTlsVersion:'TLS1_2'
    accessTier: 'Cool'
    allowBlobPublicAccess: true
    networkAcls:{
      bypass:'AzureServices'
      defaultAction:'Allow'
      virtualNetworkRules:[]
    }
    supportsHttpsTrafficOnly: true
  }
}
```

then we need to define the containers using composition

```
resource newContainers 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/blobServices/containers@2022-09-01' = [for containerName in containerNames:{
  name:'${storageAccount.name}/default/${containerName}'
  dependsOn: [storageAccount]
  properties:{
    publicAccess:'None'
  }  
}]
```

Couple things to note:

- this solution is not sanitized for invalid input
- names are case sensitive for storage account
- make sure you test the code